# What’s the role of hypothalamus in headache pathophysiology?

Tags: pain, neurology

The hypothalamus forms part of the central autonomic network, regulating body homeostasis and controlling pain. What is its role in headaches?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Hypothalamic activation during migraine attack]
This study shows that hypothalamus is key as the migraine attack generator.
https://doi.org/10.1177/0333102419867280